# SQL query to export single data row to multiple CSV rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-csv

We are trying to automate some steps and I need to setup a query to dump data on a schedule. The problem I am having is taking the single row of data from the SQL table and dumping it to multiple rows of data.
The SQL table is used for a parts order form and has fields for up to 10 parts to be entered (Part01 - Part10) and fields for quantities of each part (Qty01-Qty10). As in most orders, we are not using all 10 lines on every order, so when we export, we also need to test if there is data in the part field (PartXX<>'') to only generate rows for lines that actually have data. There are also fields in the table that would need to be populated in each output row, even though it doesn't change. The query for the first "row" is straight-forward, but my obstacle is the "IF/THEN" part for the subsequent rows and generating the "Line" for the

The output I am looking for is like this:

```
Ticket# CustID  Account  Line  ShipAttn  ShipAdd  ShipCity ShipState  ShipZip  Part Qty
123456  Cust01  987465   1     Joe Smith Address  AnyTown  IL         01234    Key  2
123456  Cust01  987456   2     Joe Smith Address  AnyTown  IL         01234    Lock 2
```

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Show us the query you've tried, sample data and possibly a table structure.

Comment: Sorry, using MS SQL 2008 R2.  </br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **pivot** table (or "crosstab"). Every RDBMS has its own solution for that, you failed to provide yours. Exact syntax also depends on your RDBMS.

A **standard-SQL** query could look like this:

```
SELECT Ticket#, CustID, Account, 1 AS Line, ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part01 AS Part, Qty01 AS Qty
FROM   tbl
WHERE  Part01 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL
SELECT Ticket#, CustID, Account, 2 AS Line, ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part02 AS Part, Qty02 AS Qty
FROM   tbl
WHERE  Part02 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL ...

ORDER BY Ticket#, CustID, Account, Line
```

`ORDER BY` is applied to the complete result, not just to the last leg of the query. Therefore you don't need a subselect or CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your exact schema, you might try something like this to unpivot your records:

```
;with cte as (
    -- Select for each Part/Qty:
    select Ticket#, CustID, Account, ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part01 as Part, Qty01 as Qty, 1 as Line
    from Orders
    where Part01 is not null and Qty01 is not null
    union all
    select Ticket#, CustID, Account, ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part02 as Part, Qty02 as Qty, 2 as Line -- 02!
    from Orders
    where Part02 is not null and Qty02 is not null -- 02!
    union all
    select Ticket#, CustID, Account, ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part03 as Part, Qty03 as Qty, 3 as Line -- 03!
    from Orders
    where Part03 is not null and Qty03 is not null -- 03!
    --union all...keep going with 04 - 10
)
select Ticket#, CustID, Account
    , row_number() over (partition by Ticket# order by Line) as Line
    , ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part, Qty
from cte
order by Ticket#, Line
```

Comment: I should note that this was tried in SQL Server since we don't know what the OP is using, but demonstrates that the `Line` will take some logic to find.

Comment: I will definitely try this on my side as an alternate to Edwin's post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both the solution above requires Union, as you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, you might want to  use inbuilt functionality of UnPivot ... It is still untested, but it should work.

It is based on the solution described : http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

```
SELECT Ticket#, CustID, Account
    , row_number() over (partition by Ticket# order by Parts) as Line
    , ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip, Part, Qty 
FROM 
( 
SELECT Ticket#, CustID, Account , ShipAttn, ShipAdd, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZip,
       Part01, Part02, Part03, Part04, Part05, Part06, Part07, Part08, Part09, Part10,
       Qty01, Qty02, Qty03, Qty04, Qty05, Qty06, Qty07, Qty08, Qty09, Qty10
FROM Suppliers 
) Main
UNPIVOT 
( 
Part FOR Parts IN (Part01, Part02, Part03, Part04, Part05, Part06, Part07, Part08, Part09, Part10) 
) P


UNPIVOT 
( 
Qty For Qtys IN (Qty01, Qty02, Qty03, Qty04, Qty05, Qty06, Qty07, Qty08, Qty09, Qty10) 
) Q

WHERE RIGHT(Parts,2) =  RIGHT(Qtys,2)
```